# Is there a standard way to use OR in an api parameter?

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest

Lets say I am calling a web api such as:

```
http://testapi.com/search?type=2
```

That would work fine for a single type, but what if I wanted type 1 and type 2. Is there a standard way to call this? I tried:

```
http://testapi.com/search?type=2|1
http://testapi.com/search?type=2&type=1
```

With no success..

Or is the only way typically to do this with web apis to make two calls and then combine the results yourself?

In case it helps - Specifically in this instance I believe the website developer has made the website and API via codeigniter.

Comment: No, there is no "standard" way to do this.  Check the API docs, see if they support sending multiple types.  If it does not, then you need to make 2 calls.

Comment: One URL is supposed to be assigned to one resource, also GET requests are idempotent. There is no way to know which resource will be returned if there will be "OR" in the URL, will it be `type=1` or `type=2` ? What will be the purpose of this?

Comment: Let's say a user is building up a more complex search using an API to return a collection of objects. They want `(type = 1 OR type = 2) AND (language = 4 OR language = 5) AND (location = 1001 OR location) = 1002`. That's alot of api calls to get what they want (8?). This is programatically possible to do with one api call if there is a standard syntax. But it appears there isn't, so ill need to put in an enhancement request on the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the comments it appears that there is no 'standard way'. If you need something like this you have two choices:

a. Place an enhancement request against the API for some custom syntax to allow `OR` (this is what I did and now use)

or

b. Right code to loop through each of the possibilities and union results.